# How Do I Remove Contact (Row) From List of Contacts (Table)

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

Hye guys,

I am building a tiny non-object oriented, non mvc, simple approach, php mysql web application. Im trying to understand basics of php and mysql before i could jump into oop and mvc. - updated as advised by nmiranda.

I have a table named 'contacts' and it has 2 columns - contact_id and contact_name. 
Assuming i formatted my page as below:

```
Buzzlair    -   Remove
Voufincci   -   Remove
Duerre      -   Remove
Watson      -   Remove
```

Each contact has a unique id (contact_id).
Assuming an admin is viewing list contacts
Assuming an admin click remove (button), the contact (only that particular contact person) should be removed.

```
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contact_id='$_POST["contact_id"]'
```

maybe the submit button will look like this

```
<input method="submit" name="$contact_id" display="hidden" />
<input method="submit" value="Remove" />
```

I believe there is something to do with contact_id. But i yet, cant find out how. Kindly advice how do i achieve this. Which method is best to use - get or post and why?

Thank you.

**Update** : I had it working already. It took me more than 6 hours of exhaustive reading and digging. uh. thanks everybody.

Comment: GET and POST are HTTP methods and have nothing to do with removing rows from a database.  You need to understand SQL "delete" statements, but more important you need to learn about multi-tier web architectures, which cannot be taught as an answer on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I acknowledge the use of DELETE statement in deleting row from database. But to use this with php, i need to use either get or post (submit form with input - submit).

Comment: I think you should provide more details like, is it a winform or a web page you are making? cause you only tag for mysql but the question is more about a program. In both cases the strategy is the same but the programming is different. In mysql you just "Delete from contacts where contact_id=1"

Comment: thanks nmiranda. i updated my details. hope it could give a better picture to others.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the admin is logged in, a get statement should be no problem. Just make the href on your remove link that points to script.php?delID=21 (where 21 is your contact_id that is dynamically added to the table row) and then set up a sql DELETE query inside script.php to watch for $_GET['delID']